# Flatness from the relation of dimensions of fibers at closed points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that if X is Cohen–Macaulay, and Y is regular, and there is a morphism $f : X \to Y$, such that for any point $x \in X$ and $y = f(x)$:

$\text{dim}_x \, X = \text{dim}_y Y + \text{dim}_x \; f^{-1}(y)$

then $f$ is flat.

If we know the relation above only for closed points $x \in X$, when is it still true that $f$ is a flat morphism?

Comment: this is Hartshorne Chapter III Exercise 10.9